# How to package a Kivy app with Pyinstaller

Tags: windows-7, kivy, pyinstaller

I have a lot of troubles following the [instructions](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-windows.html) form the Kivy website, many steps aren't explained like what should I answer to the warning.

```
WARNING: The output directory "..." and ALL ITS CONTENTS will be REMOVED! Continue? (y/n)
```

Even if I choose `y`, the folder isn't removed.

Also should I always add these lines:

- `from kivy.deps import sdl2, glew`
- `Tree('C:\\Users\\<username>\\Desktop\\MyApp\\'),`
- `*[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)]`

in the .spec file? Why are they necessary?

Not many info is available for Kivy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the line:

> ALL ITS CONTENTS will be REMOVED!

yes, it will be removed ***AND*** replaced later with new files. Check the date. I think it prints `permission denied` if it can't do such a thin both for files and the whole folder, so you'd notice it. It's important though, because you need to add additional files into your folder.

Those additional files of two types:

- kivy dependencies
- application data

Dependencies are just binaries (+/- loaders, licenses, or so), you get them through the `*[Tree(p) ...]` piece of code, which is just a command for "get all files from that folder". Without them Kivy won't even start.

Similarly to that, the second `Tree(<app folder>)` does the same, but for your own files such as `.py` files, `.kv` files, images, music, databases, basically whatever *you* create.

Obviously if you remove the deps, app won't start and if you remove app data, you'll get some path errors and most likely crash. You don't want any of that :P

Answer (score 5):

Because I spent a lot of time understanding how I should package my app, here are some instructions that would have really helped me.

Some info are available at http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/

**Python 3.6 as of march 2017**
Because packaging my app gave me the error `IndexError: tuple index out of range`, I had to install the developement version of PyInstaller:

```
pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.zip
```

**Step 1:**

I moved all the files of  `MyApp` in a folder `"C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\MyApp"`: the `.py`, the `.kv` and the images and I created an `icon.ico`.
I created another folder `C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\MyPackagedApp`. In this folder I press `Shift+right click` and select `open command window here`.

Then I pasted this:

```
python -m PyInstaller --name MyApp --icon "C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\MyApp\icon.ico" "C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\MyApp\myapp.py"
```

This creates two folders, `build` and `dist`, and a `.spec` file. In `dist/MyApp`, I can find a `.exe`. Apparently, if my app is really simple (just one label), the packaged app can works without the Step 2.

**Step 2:**

The second step involves editing the `.spec` file. [Here](https://github.com/EnoraNedelec/Kivy_PyInstaller_.spec) is an exemple of mine.
(cf Step 3, for the explanations about `my_hidden_modules`)

I go back to the `cmd`, and enter

```
python -m MyApp myapp.spec
```

I then got this warning:

```
WARNING: The output directory "..." and ALL ITS CONTENTS will be REMOVED! Continue? (y/n)
```

I enter `y` and then press `enter`.

Because I choosed y, I was surpised that the folder `build` was still there and that the `dist/MyApp` was still containing many files. But this is normal. PyInstaller can output a single file `.exe` or a single folder which contains all the script’s dependencies and an executable file. But the default output is a single folder with multiple files.

**Step 3: adding hidden modules**

When I click on the `myapp.exe` in  `dist/MyApp`, the app crashed. In the log C:\Users\.kivy\logs\ I could find 2 errors: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32timezone'` and `SystemError: <class '_frozen_importlib._ModuleLockManager'>`. 
Because of this I had to edit the .spec file and add these lines:

```
my_hidden_modules = [
         ( 'C:\\Users\\<username>\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\Lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib\\win32timezone.py', '.' )
         ]
```

in `a = Analysis` I changed `datas = []` to `datas = my_hidden_modules`,

Apparently this is because I used a `FileChooser` widget.

Answer (score 1):

It also works if in the 'a = Analysis...' block in the spec file one substitutes

```
hiddenimports=[]
```

for

```
hiddenimports=['win32file', 'win32timezone']
```

for win32file, win32timezone or for whatever files are missing